# Neither Chromium or Chrome wont start Lubuntu

Tags: chrome, lubuntu, chromium-os

Trying to install Chromium/Chrome on my Lubuntu (Ubuntu 12.04) installation.

I have followed [this](http://www.howopensource.com/2011/10/install-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-11-10-11-04-10-10-10-04/) guide to get Chrome in my repository and the installed it. But when Im trying to access it in my GUI Lubuntu over VNC Viewer nothing happens.

Same thing after uninstalling Chrome and installing Chromium, hitting the Chromium icon, nothing happens.

Im afraid Im a little bit new to this and not sure where the log file is, at least the console doesn't spit any error message when I have it up and accessing the browsers.

What can be wrong? Where should I start to troubleshot?

Answer (score -1):

Try launching from the command line in a terminal to see if there are errors on stdout or stderr.

You may be encountering [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203189/open-google-chrome-in-another-display). (VNC is not supported?)